# In what order does this happen

Tags: c++, c++14

Lets say I have an instance called `box1` , `box2` and run the code below.

```
if(box1->getSize() > box2->copyBox(box1)->getSize())
```

`getSize()` returns size of box, `copyBox(box)` copies the data of box1 to box2 not the address.

In what order does the code happen?
I thought

1. `box1->getSize()` : The size of `box1` is returned
2. `box2->copyBox(box1)` : `box2` now shares the same address as `box1` as in they're the same instance
3. `box2->getSize()` : The size of `box2` is returned
4. `>` operator : size of `box1` and `box2` is compared

I can't find what the orders are with VS2017 debugger. Can anyone tell me a way to find the order with the debugger or at least what the orders are in this example? Thanks.

Comment: Why you say you can't figure it out with a debugger?

Comment: I believe the order is not defined, because comparsion operators are not mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : I'm pretty new to C++, so i could be missing out some features of VS17 debugger. But I believe the debugger only shows what  the variables holds in breakpoints lines. It doesn't show what order the operations are excuted in same line.

Comment: @BullGom If you want to know the order of the nested function calls, you can use "Step Into" and see what function (and `this` pointer) you get. But the unspecified execution order problem remains; what you will see is just what happens to be the way the compiler did it in that one instance, and could pretty much change from one compilation to the next.

Comment: @BullGom press `F11`  to step into instructions

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : And thanks for the link.

Comment: `box2->getSize(10)` is not evaluated **at all**. Assuming that `copyBox` returns `this`, then a pointer with the same value as `box2` is dereferenced to call `getSize`

Comment: @Caleth : That is my mistake sorry. Its fixed.

Comment: @bolov : Really. Thank you.

Comment: My point still stands `box2->getSize()` isn't called, because `box2` is not the left hand side of `operator->`. It may well be that the result of `copyBox` is a copy of the `this` pointer, but that's not defined in the snippet you showed. It could be anything

Comment: @Caleth:  The copyBox was supposed to copy the datas of box1 to box2. So to do this correctly, I should've called copyBOx before the if statement, and in the if statement, just call getSize?

Comment: I don't know. If that is the goal, why have this `if ...` at all? It will never be entered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`copyBox` cannot change the address of `box2`.

`getSize(10)` is not in the above expression you are breaking down.

There are no guarantees about the order of evaluation of the lhs and the rhs of `>`.

Given `exprA > exprB`, the compiler could evaluate `exprB` first or `exprA`.  Prior to C++17 it could even evakuate part of `exprB`, pause, do par of `exprA`, the continue in `exprB`; this may have changed in C++17 (it did in some similar contexts, and I am not certain here).

It must evaluate both `exprA` and `exprB` before `>`.

This unspecified execution order exists to permit different compilers solving the problem differently.  It gives freedom to optimize, both in a given expression, and in how the compiler handles low level details like calling conventions.